# Why does my ice maker make a knocking sound and not produce ice?

Tags: repair, refrigerator

My ice maker is making knocking noises every few hours and rarely produces ice. Every now and then (once a month or so) it actually starts making ice and the noises stop for a day.

It's a GE french door with bottom freezer.

Any ideas on why it knocks and how to permanently fix this?

Edit: I checked the water intake. It's getting water and the pump sounds fine. Sounds like the knocking noise is coming from inside where the ice is made. Gonna try the defrost scenario Mike Powell suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our ice maker recently had its water inlet freeze up, preventing water from filling the trays.  The mechanism kept dutifully trying to push nonexistent ice cubes into a bin that never filled up, which might account for the knocking noise in your case.

To defrost it we just unplugged the unit, took all the food out of the freezer section, and left the door open for a couple of hours.  It wasn't long enough for any of the frozen food to defrost, and since we were careful to minimize opening the refrigerator section's door, the food in that part stayed cold enough to be safe as well.

Comment: Okay, I defrosted the freezer and it seems to be working right now. We'll have to wait and see if the problem pops up again.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if the ice maker is full of water?  It could be just running fine but not getting any/enough water. When ours stopped working this was the case, and the pump motor at the bottom of the fridge where the water line plugs in had to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of connection are you using to your water line?  Is it a copper one or one of the less expensive plastic "tap" connections?  The tap connection can get clogged and not let any water into the ice maker, which would cause a lack of ice production.

When we first bought our house, I used one of the cheap connectors and the ice maker never really worked right.  It wasn't until a plumber installed the better copper connection (and line) that it worked the way it was supposed to.

Comment: It's a copper connector. It seems to get water okay. I have defrosted the freezer and it's working so far. Time will only tell if the problem pops up again.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't defrost my freezer when it happened to me but what I did , on a hunch, was pour water over the ice maker and turned off the ice maker as it was full anyway. It stopped the knocking for days until we got low on ice and my wife turned it back on.

Comment: So turning off the ice maker stopped the noise it was making while it was operating?