# Ice Maker makes consistent clicking sound and doesn't make any ice

Tags: repair, refrigerator

I have a GE french door refrigerator with freezer on the bottom. I have seen it make 2 batches of ice. I have seen it only when I left the fridge door open for awhile when I was trying to figure out what was going on with the ice maker and when I tried defrosting the fridge (from the link below). Which leads me to believe that the arm is trying to push the ice out but it cant until maybe the ice melts a little bit. Does this make since? Ive never fixed an ice maker and I'm not sure how to fix it. The ice maker is a closed box and Im not familiar with how to diagnose the problem.

I read this and tried defrosting my fridge but that did not work. 
[Why does my ice maker make a knocking sound and not produce ice?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3264/why-does-my-ice-maker-make-a-knocking-sound-and-not-produce-ice)

This is what is making the clicking sound. I tried using a blow dryer to this device specifically and still does not work. Although it did make 1 batch of cubes...
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41EA6wxVHmL.jpg

Comment: Happens all the time. Hit it with a hair dryer until the ice melts enough and scoop it out.  arm should turn over and start making ice again.

Comment: This did not work :( I edited the post to reflect it

Comment: Another thing that causes it to grind is that if you over-pack your freezer and it accidentally shreds a plastic bag and engorges it, it can grind away for a while.

Comment: But the ice maker is not in the freezer, its in the top left door of the refrigerator. The freezer is on the bottom. So that shouldn't happen right? I feel like its the arm that pushes the ice out of the actual ice maker unit(picture link of unit in question description). But im not even sure theres an arm in the ice maker! I dont know how to pull it out to check it.

Comment: I've seen it where a chunk of ice will get stuck and freeze in the icemaker, or in the tray that collects the ice, preventing it from making and pushing out ice. Usually, you can open the cover / pull out the tray and clear out the jam.

Answer (score 1):

I pulled the ice maker out and pulled the top off of it. I then plugged it back in to the refrigerator without the top and watched the arm struggle with pushing the ice out. Given that I read that ice makers are not serviceable I purchased one of amazon for $95. I now have ice again!

Comment: After I replaced the ice maker I was only making about 1 batch of ice a day. I eventually had to change the speed of water that was coming out of the refrigerator. In my case the water came out too fast. By changing the lever on the wall where the water line was hooked up I was able to finally fix it. I know have more ice than I know what to do with. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Over the last several months my LG LSXS26326/00 has been making a clicking noise before ice cubes are dispensed (ice maker working, but noisy).  When hearing the first click open the freezer and observe if the ice maker paddles are moving smoothly and listen for the clicks.  If it jerks with each click noise, the plastic paddles are most likely somewhat stuck.  When it is stopped, gently push the paddles forward and backward.  Do they move easily?  If not, you have the same problem I had. There is mineral residue or plastic contamination or moisture in the areas (bearing) where the paddles travel.  OK, how do you fix that?

Loosen the motor/tray/paddle assembly by removing the two screws.  I took and cleaned as much of the minerals off on the end where the water is dispensed (right side).  Then I took and sprayed a small amount of WD40 into a bottle cap.  With a flat toothpick (big end) I dipped the toothpick into the WD40, which collected a small amount of oil on it.  Then I tipped the assembly back and forth to allow each application of oil to run down into the bearing surface.  After several applications of oil (a small amount) the paddles loosened up. What this appears to have done is 3 things; loosed the mineral deposits, loosened the plastic that may have worn off, and with the oil on the bearing it will prevent the accumulation of the slight amount of water to dry out and create mineral deposits.

Did it work? After an hour or two after reassembly, insert a straightened paper clip into the test hole for 10 seconds.  Then watch and listen for several minutes.  The paddles will start to move and the ice will be dispensed - be patient.  Were there any clicks?  No!  Where ice cubes dispensed? Yes?  Fixed?  I think so!

Long term - 48 hours and no clicking of ice maker!  Success.

Maybe this should be an annual maintenance procedure. This procedure might save you  a $100 to $200 depending on where you purchased the replacement - more if you had a service call.  Remember, if you have any mechanical and electrical skills, you can do this.  It is not much more difficult than replacing the water filter or cleaning a washer drain filter on a front loading washing machine.  Good Luck!

Comment: I'd probably use a better lube than WD40 (something like a light gear-type oil) but the concept's sound at least

Answer (score 0):

We also used a blow dryer to melt the ice some. This worked beautifully. The gear box immediately stopped clicking.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Answer posts are reserved for solutions to the question, and the intent is that each answer provide a solution that has not already been presented.  The question mentions the hair dryer trick and that it wasn't successful.  So a post saying that it worked in your own case isn't really a solution or a potential solution that has not already been mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

My fridgidaire was doing the same.  I used a hair dryer and nothing.  I turned water off and unplugged. I took the ice maker out and the white plastic fingers on both ends were bent inwards, blocking it from moving.  I could not unbend them enough so I ended up trimming them slightly.  All hooked up and working fine.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had that happen to my GE. There was a small piece of ice stuck in Make tray. I cleared it. Working fine now. EZ fix for me.

Answer (score 0):

The long answer: The second to last step in the ice being dumped in the ice tray is a heating element coming on that will cause the ice cubes to melt ever so slightly so when the dump arm rotates the the cubes will be able to be pushed into the bucket. When this element stops working the ice remains frozen to the mold and the dump arm is not strong enough to push the cubes. The clicking are the gears of the arm. They are made of very strong plastic but eventually the teeth break. The only solution for this particular ice maker is to replace it. The element is not replaceable. That’s the problem and answer.